# Windows Phone 7/IE9 jQuery ajax "Access is denied"

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, jquery

I'm trying to use the following code with jQuery on Windows Phone 7.5. Every time I try to make a ajax request for xml I get returned "Access is Denied" from the error handler. JSONP is not going to work in this scenario, unfortunately as the data I need is only in XML. I'm not sure how I'd go about fixing this issue.

Edit: I should point out, that the code works fine on Chrome and Safari. I don't have a Windows machine to test on IE however.
Edit 2: Tested on IE9 With the same error.

javascript:

```
function loadData(index) {
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
   $.ajax({
       url: "http://foo.bar/some.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: parseData,
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
         alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
       } 
   });
};
```

php proxy to fetch the xml

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");

$intme = date('YmdHis');
$start = $_GET['ind'];
$url = "http://some.data.source/data.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: what are you using? Phone Gap, making webapp or webcontrol inside native app?

Comment: A webapp with just plain jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how about plain JQuery, but when i worked with phonegap i faced same problem and written this:

Before making AJAX request you must allow cross-domain requests and core support, by setting:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

Those must be set in a specific-phonegap function “DeviceReady”, example:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "www/about.txt",
                dataType: 'text'
            }).done(function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                });
            });
```

**2.2.  url**

Making Windows Phone 8 oriented application, in AJAX request you MUST specify full path to resource, example:
                    url: "www/about.txt",

Making Windows Phone 8 oriented application, in AJAX request you MUST NOT specify full path to resource, example:
url: "about.txt",

**2.3.  Source File extensions**

Be careful using unknown extension files, like template extension *.tpl or similar. Sometimes AJAX doesn’t like them, I suggest using simple *.txt and *.html extensions.

**3.    getJSON**

Somehow $.getJSON doesn’t work on Windows Phone, example:

```
 $.getJSON('www/jsonfiles/jsonfile.txt',
              function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                if(status == "success") {
                    alert(data);
                }
              });
```

You can replace it with AJAX request like so:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'www/jsonfiles/jsonfile.txt',
        dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function (result) {
        Alert( JSON.parse(result));
    });
```